# Opening multiple pages at the same time does not work in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am converting a website from web forms to mvc. The website has a page which calls other web services using Threads. It takes 5 to 7 seconds to load that page. While that page is loading, if I try to open any other pages of the same website, it does not work any more. If I open other pages in new tabs they keeps loading until the first page loading (5 to 7 seconds) is complete. It used to work in web forms.

Are there any certain places that I could look into to fix this or is this just my application specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your problem description one thing that comes to mind is ASP.NET Session. If your site uses it you cannot send 2 parallel requests to a controller action that writes to the session from the same session. ASP.NET simply serializes the access to the session and will block until the first request has finished. One way to fix that would be to either completely disable the session or not write to it from the controller that you are invoking. This could be done by decorating this controller with the `[SessionState]` attribute:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ... actions in this controller can be invoked 
        in parallel from the same session
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin, we are heavily using sessions, i think this might be the issue. We are tying to fix it now!